# Can you control YN560 IV speedlights using a SB-700 in the hotshoe mount as a master?

Tags: flash, off-camera-flash, hotshoe-flash, yongnuo, sb-700

I have a SB-700 speedlight and I would like to buy a few YN560 IV speedlights. With other Nikons, I could control them with the SB-700 on the camera hotshoe using Master mode.

Can you do 100% exactly the same thing with Yongnuo YN560 IV speedlights (using the SB-700 as a master)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the Yongnuo flash naming conventions?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47702/what-are-the-yongnuo-flash-naming-conventions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What lighting gear to get after my speedlight?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16563/what-lighting-gear-to-get-after-my-speedlight). Note particularly @NickBedord's answer, that you can control YN560 flashes with SB-700.

Comment: By "using the SB-700 as a master" do you mean as a CLS master with TTL, FP/HSS, and power-setting control? Or just triggering the remote flash to fire?

Comment: @inkista Well, the same way the SB-700 could control other SB-700s.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** You can't control YN-560IVs with an SB-700 the same way an SB-700 can control another SB-700 using Nikon's Creative Lighting System (CLS). **Only the Yongnuo flashes with EX in the name have this capability**.

CLS is a proprietary optical (light pulse based) signaling protocol that requires a CLS receiver in remote flashes.  The YN-560 series of Yongnuo flashes are all manual-only flashes that don't have a CLS receiver. They do have a "dumb" optical slave sensor (similar to SU-4 mode on Nikon speedlights) that you can use with an SB-700 as a remote trigger, but only if you take the SB-700 *out* of master mode, and use it as a simple manual flash.  And the only thing it can tell the YN-560IV to do is fire in sync with the shutter. That's it. (That's what "manual only" means).

To remotely set the power or zoom on a YN-560IV, you need another YN-560IV or YN-560-TX on the camera hotshoe, and this signaling is done over radio, not with light pulses.

You may want to consider a Yongnuo YN-568EX, etc. or a CLS-slave capable flash from Nissin, Metz, Godox, Phottix, etc. etc. instead. Look in specs and reviews for whether or not the flash can be used as a CLS slave. Be careful of any claims for "TTL optical triggering" as they may not be referring to CLS, but a simple "dumb" optical triggering mode that can ignore a TTL pre-flash and fire at the correct time.

See also:

- [What are the Yongnuo flash naming conventions?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47702/what-are-the-yongnuo-flash-naming-conventions)
- [Are Yongnuo flashes interchangeable between dslr's or are they brand specific?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62373)